# How do I check win32 native copyfile() work or where can I get document to check how win32 native copyfile() work?

Tags: c#, memory-management, visual-studio-2017, out-of-memory, file-copying

I got a question about how does win32native CopyFile work.
Does it work like using FileStream read and write bytes?
or it will allocate the memory first to ensure it got enough memory then start copy?
I had check the document and open source provided by Microsoft.
But both of them didn't mentioned how does it work.

The reason I want to check for how win32native CopyFile work is I got a program using FileInfo.CopyTo(), but got "Not enough storage" issue.
After I change FileInfo.CopyTo() to filestream Read() and Write() then it work.
So I would like to check how does win32native CopyFile work thanks!

Comment: Implementation details of OS functions are intentionally not documented and can be changed at any time, so should not be relied upon. Are you sure your stream code copies the file correctly and fully?

Comment: @GSerg the win32 apis are heavily documented and have been so for years.

Comment: @TheGeneral Please point me to documentation of implementation details of win32 apis (rather than their public interface and the description of the observable effects).

Comment: @GSerg Oh, I think I see what you are saying. That the source code is not available. However regardless ,the apis are documented well. And to answer the question, no FileStream would be using CreateFile and subsequent apis, while FileInfo.CopyTo would be using FileCopyEx. As to why one is working and not the other, this would seem strange. What is the media you are trying to read from, is it just a standard drive, or a file share, or a unc path, or something else?

Comment: @TheGeneral No, `FileInfo.CopyTo` uses [just `CopyFile`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,168). Which is why the OP is asking how it works internally - which they can only learn by reverse engineering Windows, and most often it's a [wrong thing to do](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/).

Comment: @TheGeneral, I am trying to read from a file share, with using the filestream read/write the file trying to copy is correctly and fully.
I read some document  about the CopyFile , it mentioned CopyFile will allocate 256KB or 64 KB first depends on the file size then start copy, but I am using  filestream read/write as 4KB size.
Would it be possible for the rest of memory less than the memory that CopyFile need. Not sure this is the root cause or not, so that's why I am asking how does win32 CopyFile work, thansk!!